# How to unit test a decorated method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-decorators

Assume I have to unit test `methodA`, defined in the following class:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def wrapper(fun):
        def _fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.b = 'Original'
            fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return _fun

    @wrapper
    def methodA(self):
        pass
```

My test class is as follows:

```
from mock import patch

class TestSomeClass(object):

    def testMethodA(self):
        def mockDecorator(f):
            def _f(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.b = 'Mocked'
                f(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return _f

        with patch('some_class.SomeClass.wrapper', mockDecorator):
            from some_class import SomeClass
            s = SomeClass()
            s.methodA()
            assert s.b == 'Mocked', 's.b is equal to %s' % s.b
```

If I run the test, I hit the assertion:

```
File "/home/klinden/workinprogress/mockdecorators/test_some_class.py", line 17, in testMethodA
    assert s.b == 'Mocked', 's.b is equal to %s' % s.b
AssertionError: s.b is equal to Original
```

If I stick a breakpoint in the test, after patching, this is I can see `wrapper` has been mocked out just fine, but that `methodA` still references the old wrapper:

```
(Pdb) p s.wrapper
<bound method SomeClass.mockDecorator of <some_class.SomeClass object at 0x7f9ed1bf60d0>>
(Pdb) p s.methodA
<bound method SomeClass._fun of <some_class.SomeClass object at 0x7f9ed1bf60d0>>
```

Any idea of what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mulling over, I've found a solution.

Since monkey patching seems not to be effective (and I've also tried [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15701244/222529) 
[other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667621/222529) solutions), I dug into the function internals and that proved to be fruitful.

**Python 3**
You're lucky - just use the `wraps` decorator, which creates a `__wrapped__` attribute, which in turn contains the wrapped function. See the linked answers above for more details.

**Python 2**
Even if you use `@wraps`, no fancy attribute is created.
However, you just need to realise that the wrapper method does nothing but a closure: so you'll be able to find your wrapped function in its `func_closure` attribute.

In the original example, the wrapped function would be at: `s.methodA.im_func.func_closure[0].cell_contents`

**Wrapping up** (ha!)
I created a `getWrappedFunction` helper along this lines, to ease my testing:

```
@staticmethod
def getWrappedFunction(wrapper):
    return wrapper.im_func.func_closure[0].cell_contents
```

YMMV, especially if you do fancy stuff and include other objects in the closure.