# Bypass decorator with mock in django test

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write a simple test however my views are decorated with nested user_passes_test statements.  They check things like a stripe subscription and is_authenticated.  I have found various posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698425/overriding-decorator-during-unit-test-in-python) which address how to bypass a decorator with patch but I can't quite work out how to integrate everything together.

tests.py

```
@patch('dashboard.views.authorised_base_user_checks', lambda func: func)
def test_dashboard_root_exists(self):
    response = self.client.get('/dashboard/')
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

decorator in views

```
def authorised_base_user_checks(view_func):
    decorated_view_func = login_required(user_active(subscriber_exists(subscriber_valid(view_func))))
    return decorated_view_func
```

views.py

```
@authorised_base_user_checks
def IndexView(request):
    ...
```

The above still fails to pass through the decorator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This approach with patching of decorator most probably does not work because import of `views` module happens after the patching. If `view` has been already imported the decorator had been already applied to `IndexView` and patching the decorator function would have no effect at all.

You can reload the view module to overcome this:

```
import imp
import dashboard.views

@patch('dashboard.views.authorised_base_user_checks', lambda func: func)
def test_dashboard_root_exists(self):
   # reload module to make sure view is decorated with patched decorator
   imp.reload(views)

   response = self.client.get('/dashboard/')
   self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)

   # reload again
   patch.stopall()
   imp.reload(views)
```

Disclaimer: this code only demonstrates the idea. You need to make sure `stopall` and final reload always happens, so they should be in `finally` or in `tearDown`.

Comment: The code was there to give the idea, I haven't run it etc. The last `patch` had incorrect name of the function. I fixed it now

Comment: Thanks I updated mine with those changes ... is that stack trace what you would expect if the decorator was still being called or is it perhaps something different?

Comment: Just checked and the `def authorised_base_user_checks(view_func):` code isn't actually being called at all as I put a set trace in there and it wasn't activated

Comment: Sorry, my idea with mocking decorator internals was misleading as it will not work in this case (namely because there's no actual function invocation in decorator, it uses other functions to wrap).

Comment: no problems thanks for trying... the above still fails unfortunately, I guess the nesting is complicating things, I'll have to have more of a look around.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I use both approaches in my projects without any problem. The approach with reloading should work in your case as well.  Mocking internals works if your decorator invokes the wrapped function directly (so unfortunately not in your case).