# Mock a decorator function to bypass decorator logic

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying write some unittests for my code which in turn uses a decorator

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from functools import wraps

def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(x):
        return f(x+1)
    return decorated

@decorator
def get_value(x):
    return x
    
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('file.decorator', lambda f: f)
    def test_something(self):
        result = get_value(1)
        self.assertEqual(1, result)
```

I'm trying to mock the decorated function to just return f and completely bypass the decorator logic part. This is talked about in [Overriding decorator during unit test in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698425/overriding-decorator-during-unit-test-in-python) but doesn't really work.

Comment: `decorator` has already been called by the time your test runs; it runs immediately after `get_value` is defined. It's too late to mock it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the decorator runs immediately after you define `get_value`, it's too late to mock the decorator. What you can do, though, (since you used `functools.wraps`) is mock `get_value` itself and use `get_value.__wrapped__` (the original function) in some way. Something like

```
@patch('tmp.get_value', get_value.__wrapped__)
def test_something(self):
    result = get_value(1)
    self.assertEqual(1, result)
```

(In this case, I put your original code, with the above change, in `tmp.py`, and ran it as `python3 -munittest tmp.py`, hence my patching of the reference `tmp.get_value`.)

If you anticipate the need to test the undecorated original, though, it might be simpler to keep it under its own (private) name to test: no patching needed.

```
import unittest
from functools import wraps

def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(x):
        return f(x+1)
    return decorated

def _get_value(x):
    return x

get_value = decorator(_get_value)
    
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        result = _get_value(1)
        self.assertEqual(1, result)
```

Comment: Great answer. In addition I would like to point out that unit testing should only be used for public interfaces and stable concepts. Testing implementation details - for example testing a wrapped function - can limit the changeability of said code, as these test cases are easy to break.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However the test case I provided might be a bit oversimplified. In my use case the decorated function has more complex logic that needs to run. I suppose I need to rethink my approach here