# Patch with decorator a decorator

Tags: python, mocking, decorator, patch

I'd like to patch a function which is called inside a decorator with the python mock library. I fail to be able to patch it though, resulting in the original function being called. It probably has to do with namespaces but it's not clear to me what I should use as function name, the first argument to the patch decorator.

What I have is the following:

```
def is_always_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode():
    return True

class ToolsTests(BaseTestCase):
    @patch('tools.is_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode', is_always_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode)
    @parameters()
    def test_benchmarks_in_x86_not_x64_folder(self):
        ... 
        #do some testing where the test decorator parameters should believe we're in 64 bit mode 
        ...
```

BaseTestCase derives from unittest.TestCase and is defined in some other module.
In that same module I have the decorator itself:

```
def parameters(*parameters):
    def decorator(method, parameters=parameters):
        if tools.is_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode():
            regressions_folder = "Regressions_x64"
        else:
            regressions_folder = "Regressions"
        # etc etc
    return decorator
```

The problem is that tools.is_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode is called, not my own  is_always_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode.

Searching for answers is a tad difficult as it's about decorating a decorator, if there's one out there already, I'm sorry for creating a redundant question.

Comment: This isn't really about decorators; that it is called inside a decorator is not an issue here. What is `tools`, is that a top-level module or something in a package?

Comment: Hm, interesting. But to answer your question: it's a module in a different package.

Comment: So you'll need to use the full package name to patch. `package.tools. is_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode`.

Comment: `def is_always_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode:` should be `def is_always_running_on_Windows_64bit_mode():`. `Class ToolsTests(BaseTestCase):` should be `class ToolsTests(BaseTestCase):`.

Comment: Thanks, updated.
@martijn: I've tried all sorts of naming as I expected to be exactly that but haven't been able to fix it. To complete the question I think I need to write a proper simple version that runs and shows it's not working but alas do not have enough time for this. Thank you though. Of: dankjewel.

Comment: This can help maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667567/can-i-patch-a-python-decorator-before-it-wraps-a-function