# Mocking decorators in python with mock and pytest

Tags: python, testing, mocking, decorator, pytest

How to patch my custom decorator with monkeypatch or pytest.mock? i manage to mock it by doing (answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667567/can-i-patch-a-python-decorator-before-it-wraps-a-function) question):

`package.decorator = mytestdecorator`

The problem is that it breaks some other tests where i actually need that decorator to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to control complete lifecycle of your mocked decorator and revert the decorator back to original state.

It can be done in few different ways:

- context manager which builds the mocked decorator, and reverts it back by `__exit__`.
- setup and teardown functions for your test, `teardown` must revert the decorator.
- `pytest` fixture with finalizer
- `pytest` fixture with `yield` expression.

Personally I like the [`@pytest.yield_fixture`](https://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html?highlight=fixture) as it keeps the code short and as soon as you realize, that all what comes after `yield` statement in the fixture code is cleanup code, things are very clear to do.

Comment: can you also provide an example?