# Python deactivate loguru.logger.catch() function when run in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, loguru

I am using loguru.logger.catch() function to log some outputs. Also, I want to deactivate this function when I test my class with pytest. I've tried to use monkey patch but didn't work. How can I handle this situation?

Example Code:

```
class DividerClass:

    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

        if self.num2 == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        else:
            self.result = self.num1 / self.num2
            logger.info(f"DividerClass {self.num1} / {self.num2} = {self.result}")


def test_divider_class_with_zero(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(loguru.logger, "catch", lambda x: x)
    
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        DividerClass(0, 0)
```

Comment: elaborate on why it doesn't work, what does your test produce?

Comment: I try to test only this situation. Actually, the main code is very long. I want to only check the concept. However, this code snippet does not work.

Comment: yes but explain why this code snippet does not work, what does it produce?

Comment: This is error: in __init__
    raise ZeroDivisionError

ZeroDivisionError

test.py:242 (test_divider_class_with_zero)
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x11e69c340>

    def test_divider_class_with_zero(monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr(loguru.logger, "catch", lambda x: x)
    
        with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
>           DividerClass(0, 0)
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes down to *when* the decorator is applied. By the time test collection has finished, the decorator is already applied to the function. Due to this we have two options:

1. Import the desired object *after* patching
2. Reload the module *after* patching

In the code below I show the former approach. This code also assumes your test files live in a separate file from your actual code.

```
# src/manager.py

from loguru import logger

class DividerClass:

    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

        if self.num2 == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        else:
            self.result = self.num1 / self.num2
            logger.info(f"DividerClass {self.num1} / {self.num2} = {self.result}")


# tests/test_manager.py

import pytest
import loguru

def test_divider_class_with_zero(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(loguru.logger, "catch", lambda x: x)
    # notice the import happens after the patch
    from src.manager import DividerClass
    
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        DividerClass(0, 0)
```

---

```
=============================================== test session starts ================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, xdist-2.5.0, forked-1.4.0, hypothesis-6.48.1, mock-3.7.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 1 item                                                                                                   

tests/test_manager.py .                                                                                      [100%]

================================================ 1 passed in 0.02s =================================================
```

Please read this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890916/6817835) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the loguru disable method `logger.disable(None)`.

Depending on the structure of you code, you can pass along the module's name instead of None to disable logging just for that module.

With `logger.enable(...)` you can afterwards re-enable logging for the other tests.

See [the loguru documentation for the disable method](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.disable) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I want to use monkeypatch actually. Is it possible?

Comment: This answer works and is super easy to implement.