# Unittest Patch not altering decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I've been having a great deal of trouble regarding Unittest.mock.patch

After much research and crawling SO, I've broken down and decided to ask the people brighter than myself.

Below is a simple function to add two ints with a decorator, which in turn will add one more to the result of add. My goal is to mock the original decorator so I am able to test just the add function.

Thank you for any help!

File Structure

```
project_folder/
│
├── test_script.py
└── add.py
```

add.py

```
####Decorator
def decor(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        result = func(*arg, **kwargs)
        return result + 1
    return wrapper

@decor
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

#Result add(1,1) == 3
```

test_script.py

```
def mock_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper


with patch('add.decor', new=mock_decorator):
    # import 'add' after patching
    from add import add as patched_add

    #pytest test function
    def test_add():
        result = patched_add(1, 1)
        assert result == 2
```

```
--Result
    def test_add():
        result = patched_add(1, 1)
>       assert result == 2
E       assert 3 == 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I patch a Python decorator before it wraps a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667567/can-i-patch-a-python-decorator-before-it-wraps-a-function)

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for the assistance! It seems that the example you mentioned involves the decorator and the function being in separate modules. However, in my case, both the function and the decorator reside in the same module. Despite extensive research, I haven't found a way to mock a decorator when it's in the same module as the function it's applied to. I hope my assumption is incorrect.